# Functional test with Minitest and authentication

Tags: testing, cookies, functional-testing, minitest

I'm trying to do functional test but I don't know how to deal with cookies.
I'm using Ruby and Minitest to do functional test of controllers.
But to run tests in controllers, first I need to authenticate.
The authentication uses cookies to see if the user is logged or not.
The problem is functional tests do not see what is in cookies, than I can't authenticate and then run tests. Does someone give me a tip to resolve this?

thanks
Heber

Comment: I have the same question. Any luck with this?

Comment: Which gem you are using for authentication? Devise or Sorcery?
Because they have provided their test helpers for user sign_in and sign_out for functional tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the same issue, myself. Being somewhat new at this, I'm not actually sure this will work, but I intend to try using the `before do` hook to run an authentication.

Something to this effect:

```
    before do
      get :login
      # fill in and submit
    end

    it "must do stuff" do
      #Test things and hopefully it'll be logged in
    end
```